# Alert on multiseries from grafana and telegraf

Tags: monitoring, grafana, influxdb

I have about 100 servers which I am monitoring via telegraf. What I want to do is set up an alert so that if one of them gets high cpu usage (<90%). I will receive an email saying [server 5 has high cpu usage] I can do this for one server. Just having trouble setting up alerts accross a muliple series query. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesnt seem to be I just generated new dashboards for each server using the api